# Endomorphism ring of finite-dimensional representation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

If $G$ is any group and $V$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $G$, then we can form the endomorphism ring $E = End_G(V)$. Suppose that $V$ is indecomposable, i.e. not a direct sum of subrepresentations.

Quals problem:(i) show that the nilpotent elements of $E$ form a two-sided ideal $I$ of $E$. (ii) Show that this ideal is nilpotent, i.e. there exists $n$ such that $I^n = 0$.

For (i) The part that I'm blanking on is why a sum of nilpotents would be nilpotent. A useful side fact here is that any element of $E$ is a scalar plus a nilpotent, so I was thinking perhaps it's just a linear algebra fact that a sum of nilpotents can't be unipotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially Fitting's lemma: for any endomorphism $f$ of $V$ we have
$$V=\mathrm{ker}(f^n) \oplus \mathrm{im}(f^n)$$ where $n$ is the dimension of $V$ (key point of proof of this lemma: the sequence of subspaces $\mathrm{ker}(f) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(f^2) \subseteq \cdots$ stabilizes after at most $n$ steps for dimension reasons).

Since $f$ commutes with $G$ the summands here are $G$-submodules, and by indecomposability one or the other is equal to $V$: so $f$ is either nilpotent or invertible. Evidently if $f$ is nilpotent then $fg$ and $gf$ are not invertible for any endomorphism $g$; these are therefore nilpotent. If $f$ and $g$ are nilpotents with $f+g$ invertible, then for some endomorphism $h$ 
$$hf+hg=h(f+g)=1 \quad \implies \quad hg=1-hf.$$ But $hf$ being nilpotent means $1-hf$ is invertible, contradicting $hg$ nilpotent. So $f+g$ is not invertible and is therefore nilpotent.

(We have proved that the endomorphism ring of an indecomposable module is a local ring; the converse is also true).

Comment: You might want to add that along with the ascending chain of kernels terminating, the descending chain of images also terminates. It's very important that the modules all have finite length (which is trivial here by finite-dimensionality.)

Comment: Thanks! Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't quite settle the issue about the nilpotence of the ideal itself?

Comment: @Tony, no, of course you are right that it does not. Sorry about that---I interpreted your question as asking only about why the sum of nilpotents was nilpotent. The fact that the ideal $I$ of nilpotents is nilpotent follows from Nakayama's lemma. Specifically, by dimension reasons there is some $d$ for which $I^d=I^{d+1}=I (I^d)$, so since $I$ is the unique maximal ideal, NAK implies $I^d=0$.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh, Sure, although I think your points are obvious enough that Tony, at least, won't be confused, and the point of the answer is to deduce from Fitting's lemma what Tony was asking about rather than to give a detailed proof of the lemma itself (most graduate programs expect their students to know it).

Comment: I get what you mean. I just wanted to point out that this property only really depends on the fact that objects in the category have finite length.

Comment: Ah, great. Somehow I never learned that there was a non-commutative Nakayama's lemma!

Comment: @Tony, Even better, the proof of the non-commutative version isn't really any harder! NAK is one of my favorite examples of a "trivial" fact that is extremely useful.